Why am I getting an error trying to use spatial search in Solr?
I am trying to find all points(lat,lng values) that are within a 5 km radius with this line
{!geofilt sfield=latlng}&pt=45.15,-93.85&d=5
where latlng is the name of the field in my schema that defines the class=solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType and the field type is location_rpt
I have tried location as the field type as well and get the same error.
IN the SOlr UI, the error message I get is msg: pt missing.
These are images of error message:
The message I receive in Solr UI query page
error":{
"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
"msg":"pt missing.",
"code":400
}
The error message I receive in vscode
"error":{
"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"],
"msg":"Exception writing document id 1 to the index; possible analysis error: cannot change field "latlng" from index options=NONE to inconsistent index options=DOCS",
"code":400
}
Tried location and location_rpt field types as well as changing the parameters to the field definition and field type definition using Schema API

Regarding 1: you've entered everything into the q argument - the pt argument  is a separate argument has to be included separately in the query string instead of as part of the q parameter. Regarding 2: you have to delete the whole index by stopping Solr and then deleting the core data directory, not just the documents.
